# javascript slider

Tags: looking-for-a-script, jquery

Help me find javascript slider. I can't find it anywhere - i just saw it one time and was shocked, how it was good implemented.

So, it looks like image below:

```
         _____
----.----|    |----.----
  1 . 2  | 3  | 4  . 5
----.----|____|----.----
```

On center (3) image is zoomed and bigger, than others

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery [Sliding Gallery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SlidingGallery) plugin enlarges the central image in the way you describe. There's a [demo here.](http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm)

Comment: [jQueryUI.com](http://jqueryui.com/) might be another good place to look around - there are a variety of pre-fab controls which, if you like the slider, you'll probably find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Flow Slider jQuery plugin:

[Flow Slider](http://www.flowslider.com)